# I want to upload a user image with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload a user image with Laravel. I upload the photo to the storage folder, but it doesn't appear on my visual view page.How can I change the path of a photo?
My Codes:
File Name:Controller

```
public function postSaveAccount(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required| max:50'
    ]);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->first_name = $request['first_name'];
    $user->update();
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename =  $request['first_name']. '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
    if($file) {
        Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, File::get($file));
    }
    return redirect()->route('account');
}
public function getUserImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

My Codes:

File Name: account.blade.php

```
<section class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>Your Account</h3></header>
        <form action="{{route('account.save')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{$user->first_name}}" id="first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image (Only.jpg)</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Account</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">

        </form>
    </div>
</section>
@if(Storage::disk('local')->has($user->first_name. '-' . $user->id . '.jpg'))
<section class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="{{route('account.image',['filename' => $user->first_name. '-' .$user->id. '.jpg']) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the problem is? What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: There is no error with the page. but the visual dashboard I installed does not appear in the section

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without more information... did you inspect the page? is the `<img>` present? Did you check the storage folder to see if images are properly uploaded?

Comment: I definitely agree with the difficult, but let me explain, I'm uploading the photo with a bi form and I want to show the photo in The View section. the file is loaded successfully, but the file path does not appear because of the photo and I can change the path of the file with the code in the controller section and how I can install it

Comment: Can you update your related route ?

Comment: thanks solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload an image like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $imgLocation = Storage::disk('public')->put(time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(), $request->gif), $request->file('image'));

    // you may need this to save it in an image model / table if dont skip this creation
    $image = Image::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'path' => $imgLocation
    ]);

    if ($video) {
        return response()->json("Success!");
    }

    return response()->json("Error!");

    // You can also return redirect()->route('image.index')...
}
```